# How to add additional express routes in react server side rendering to use as backend

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, server-side-rendering, react-router-dom

Find **Edits** at the bottom.

I have been really researching a lot of tutorials and even the documentation of the react training server side rendering located here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering

Something that has been a problem for me is using other routes in order to have a full stack application. So for example we will use the MERN stack
(`mongodb` `express` `React/Redux` `nodejs`). Lets say we have two routes in the

`app.js` like so:

```
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/posts', posts);
```

and our Server Side Rendering is set up like most of these tutorials, actually I couldn't find one that did not set it up this way, and to save time I will just put where the SSR code would go. If you don't know how to do SSR then please look at the docs in the link I gave above. I think it may not be needed, but if it is let me know and I could add a simple set up.

Something like:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => { //server side rendering code here});
```

So the problem here is that it hits every route and inside of server side rendering for `React Router 4`, most people will use `matchRoutes` function and pass in their routes that they use for the react side.

Okay so I have explained a lot, but not really what the problem is:

**PROBLEM:** When on the react side, lets say using an action and we will use axios for a simple example here.

If I do:

```
axios.get('/posts')
.then(response => { 
 console.log(response.data);
 })
.catch(err => {
 console.log(err);
 });
```

This runs into a problem. And for any of you who know express and SSR well you will know why. The `app.get('*')` is hitting every route or in better words every route request will go through here, the problem is that when we send a request to `/posts` one of two cases will happen.

**Case 1:** there is a client side route `/posts` in the routes file for react side and this case will return the server side html as the `response.data` which is obviously not what we want.

**Case 2:** there is no client side route `/posts` in the routes file for react side and this case will return a 404 error or something similar to route or page not found if you set up your SSR correctly.

I need a way to be able to use my back-end, but be able to use the SSR for react as well.

**Possible Solution?**

1. Use some type of proxy and say if `/api/routename` then use the proxy that way your calls don't get pushed through the `app.get('*')`.
2. Or some way of only doing SSR on individual routes.
3. Or excluding certain routes, but being able to use all of the client side routes. In this I mean if I have client side `/users` and an express side `/users`, I don't want the client side to break if I exclude `/users`, but some how still exclude the express side.

I'm not totally sure how to do these solutions of if they are possible, but I need to be able to use my express routes, and I can't find a concrete way on how to do it, or what is best practice.

**EDITS:**

server side app.js:

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-0', 'stage-1']
});

const pkg_json = require('./package.json');
const vertex = require('vertex360')({ site_id: pkg_json.app });
var renderer = require('./renderer.js');

// initialize app
const app = vertex.app();

// import routes
const index = require('./routes/index');
const api = require('./routes/api');
const users = require('./routes/users');

// set routes
app.use('/api/users', users);

// hopefully will be used on every Route, this should handle SSR RR4
app.use(renderer);

module.exports = app;
```

renderer.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

import routes from './src/routes';
import createStore from './src/stores';

function handleRender(req, res) {
  const store = createStore.configure(null); // create Store in order to get data from redux

  const promises = matchRoutes(routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route }) => {
      // Matches the route and loads data if loadData function is there
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null;
    })
    .map(promise => {
      if (promise) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          promise.then(resolve).catch(resolve); // lets all data load even if route fails
        });
      }
    });

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    const context = {};
    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(301, context.url); // redirect for non auth users
    }

    if (context.notFound) {
      res.status(404); // set status to 404 for unknown route
    }

    const content = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
          <div>{renderRoutes(routes)}</div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    const initialState = serialize(store.getState());

    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

    res.render('index', { content, initialState, helmet });
  });
}

module.exports = handleRender;
```

React entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

import routes from './src/routes';
import createStore from './src/stores';

function handleRender(req, res) {
  const store = createStore.configure(null); // create Store in order to get data from redux

  const promises = matchRoutes(routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route }) => {
      // Matches the route and loads data if loadData function is there
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null;
    })
    .map(promise => {
      if (promise) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          promise.then(resolve).catch(resolve); // lets all data load even if route fails
        });
      }
    });

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    const context = {};
    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(301, context.url); // redirect for non auth users
    }

    if (context.notFound) {
      res.status(404); // set status to 404 for unknown route
    }

    const content = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
          <div>{renderRoutes(routes)}</div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    const initialState = serialize(store.getState());

    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

    res.render('index', { content, initialState, helmet });
  });
}

module.exports = handleRender;
```

Comment: I personally prepend all my api routes with a /api.
Also if you place your * route at the end, after all the other routes, then all your api routes won't reach the * route, only the ssr requests would reach them.

Comment: Thank you I'll give this a try and let you know what I find tomorrow

Comment: @VivekN I am getting an error stating `window is not defined` when I put my routes before the SSR , whenever I make a call to them that is.

Comment: please post your entire express index.js file, so that I can check it once.

Comment: I made a separate post for this , but I do not think I can link my other post in here, I will go ahead and add the express file for you though, I also added the react entry point, after some discussion with fellow teammates they believe this is where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VivekN, the way you do this is make sure that your 
`app.get('*')` is below each of the declared routes. This should allow your other routes to be passed through first.